# Laravel redis cache tag not cleared?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

In my Laravel 5.4 project I use redis. I've got a `EloquentRepo.php` with these functions:

```
public function findBy($column, $value, $with = [])
{
    return $this->cache->tags($this->getModel())->remember($this->getModel().'|find_by|'.$column.'|'.$value, 60, function () use ($column, $value, $with) {
        return $this->_model->where($column, $value)->with($with)->first();
    });
}
```

And

```
public function paginate($page, $with = [])
{
    return $this->cache->tags($this->getModel())->remember($this->getModel().'|paginate|'.$page, 60, function () use ($page, $with) {
        return $this->_model
            ->with($with)
            ->paginate(10);
    });
}
```

`$this->cache` is reference to

```
use Illuminate\Cache\Repository as CacheRepository;
```

I've got an Organisation.php model with a observer class. The updated method in that observer class looks like this:

```
public function updated(Organisation $organisation)
{
    $this->cache->tags(Organisation::class)->flush();
    $this->cache->tags(Relation::class)->flush();
}
```

The organisation cache tags are being flushed properly. But the relation cache tags are not being flushed at all (I can see that in the `redis-cli` with `keys *`)

I use the same methods in the repository to get the data so what could be the problem here?